# Moving page when pasting items

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

First of all sorry for not including any code from my attempts as I don't even know where to begin to start trial coding. What Im trying to do is I have a sheet which I have pre formatted to be my report. I then use a macro to copy certain columns from one sheet to the report sheet. I need to report sheet to be singed by somebody in the business and therefore need the bottom few rows for that. My question is how do I get the pasted columns to paste onto the next sheet if they reach a line that I decided is the last line I would like any information on. I apologise for the very vague question so please ask questions if you need any more info.

Comment: You will not be able to copy entire columns. You will have to go by range or row by row.  Have a test in there for the bottom of the sheet. At that point move to then next sheet. Maybe just loop through sheets and do your pasting in the loop.

Comment: @MatthewD thanks for the reply. By next sheet I mean page on the same worksheet. Is there any function to detect the end of the page or do you suggest that I just tell it once it has counted a set amount move to next sheet?

Comment: Activesheet has .VPageBreak and .HPageBreaks that will give you the rows to work with.  I have never used them though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261092/ms-excel-vba-border-around-each-printed-page

Answer (score 0):

Loop Horizontal page breaks. Something like this.

```
For x = 1 To .HPageBreaks.Count - 1

    MsgBox .HPageBreaks(x).Location.Row

    'Write your rows adding your "sheet" row value to the pagebreak rows.
    ws.Range("D" & lRow + .HPageBreaks(x).Location.Row).Value = "SomeValue"

Next
```